How to prove $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\ln(n)}{n} e^{in\theta}\right)$ is convergent?
The problem is that:
for $0<\theta<2\pi$,
Prove
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\ln(n)}{n} e^{in\theta}\right)$$
is convergent.
The problem has a hint as $|e^{i\theta}-1|=2|\sin(\theta/2)|$ but I don't know how to use it:(
I tried to use $$\lim_{ n \to \infty }|{\frac{\ln(n)}{n} e^{in\theta}} |^{1/n}<1$$to solve it
but is seems that$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty }|{\frac{\ln(n)}{n} e^{in\theta}} |^{1/n}=1$$
I also tried for $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\cos(n\theta)$ and  $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\sin(n\theta)$ but i don't know if they are convergent.
any help or hint please :(

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Welcome to MSE. 1) Maybe the hint is for: $-2\left|\sin(n\theta/2)\right|+1 \leq e^{in\theta} \leq 2\left|\sin(n\theta/2)\right|+1$ then use some convergence of two lower / upper bound. 2) On the other hand, your post doesn’t have some required contexts. Please add some additional texts(your attempts to the problem or something else) to make your question more specific.

$e^{n\theta i}$ may not be a real number

Sorry, it has a condition that $0<\theta<2\pi$

but how to prove $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\cos(n\theta)$ and  $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\sin(n\theta)$  are convergent? It seems more difficult

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

You can apply Dirichlet test, or mimic the proof to your case. It is based on summation by parts.

That's it. Thanks!

Abel transformation should work, otherwise sum by lots (alter’ative series)
